# How to println from a txt file in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, groovy, svn, jenkins-pipeline

So I have a file called "text1.txt" that has only one line -

```
version.build=846
```

I want to do something like this-

```
def svntag = ccsmp_v_ {version.build}
println $svntag

ccsmp_v_846
```

Is there any way to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read a file from the workspace using the methods from [pipeline utility steps](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-utility-steps/) plugin.

For your case it would be best to use `readProperties` method, for example:

```
def properties = readProperties file: '<your properties file in the workspace>'
```

Then you can access the value with:

```
def svntag = "ccsmp_v_${properties['version.build']}"
```